# JFileChooser or need to use something else

Tags: java, filechooser

I am plannind to do a POC and the basic requirements for my application:

I am trying to import a file (or) files
- Option for MultiSelect
- Options for thumbnails (apart from Details and List) mainly for images
- Support for both Windows and MAC

While looking at options like JFileChooser or XFileDialog, there were some limitations. Any suggestions or leads related to overcoming limitations (e.g. multi selection) is appreciated.

Regards!
- Pranav

Comment: What specific limitations do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what the limitation are.

The Swing tutorial on [How to Use File Choosers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#advancedexample) has an example that shows how to use a "preview panel" to show a thumbnail image.

Comment: Also that swing tutorial contains info about multiselection `void setMultiSelectionEnabled(boolean)`